# Ошибки верстки, едет верстка в IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, html, javascript, вёрстка, css

Доброго времени суток!
Сверстал страницу, тут можно посмотреть: http://91.122.62.102
Первый и основной вопрос, почему верстка очень сильно едет в IE9? Что не так?
И второе, представьте что вы строгий препод в супер-крутом универе, и проверяете грамотность верстки, вас бесят самые мелкие ошибки CSS\HTML. Так вот, скажите какие ошибки и где я допустил при верстке, как их избежать, что на что заменить, и на сколько критичны найденные вами ошибки.
Я учусь, и буду признателен за качественную критику)

Answer (score 2):

> почему верстка очень сильно едет в IE9?

Здравствуйте, меня зовут IE9 и я не знаю, что такое inline-block...

Из справки на [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display): список возможных значений этого свойства, понимаемый разными браузерами очень короткий — block, inline, list-item и none. Все остальные допустимые значения поддерживаются браузерами выборочно.

> И второе, представьте что вы строгий препод...

А еще я ленивый, поэтому просто открываю [валидатор от W3C](http://validator.w3.org/) и вбиваю туда вашу страничку. Хм... 23 Errors, 5 warning(s), я думаю, мы с Вами увидимся на следующей пересдаче, следующий (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ

Comment: пофиксил ошибки. Значит если в валидаторе нет сейчас ошибок, то все круто? или же есть какие-то особенности правильной про-верстки? вот я думаю что то что есть можно улучшить, т.к. я новичок в этом, и мне кажется что можно сделать намного лучше, но я не знаю как. То что я сделал - это работает, но правильно ли это? в принципе в этом вопрос...

Comment: @sanu0074, если препод очень злой, то вряд ли он примет верстку даже от сэра Тима Бёрнерса-Ли.  
Тут только бумажка с Франклином поможет, хотя может и Мак-Кинли поднапрячь придётся.  
По сабжу - пошли препода на известное направление, нечего рудиментарные останки веба поддерживать, они только тухнут и разлагаются, задерживают разработчика.

Comment: Ну еще можно сказать, что для меню обычно используются списки, подобно ul>li>a или при использовании HTML5 тег menu, заместо простого a(уж слишком криво выглядит это сейчас). Посмотрите примеры горизонтального меню. И я не могу судить о форматирование исходного кода, но его тоже лучше держать в порядке, соблюдая отступы и логические блоки. В остальном на сайте htmlbook, в разделе "сайт" можно посмотреть на различные макеты и способы верстки. Еще ради интереса можете почитать коротенькую, но интересную книжицу "Не заставляйте меня думать" Стива Круга, но это про юзабилити.

Comment: Что? Даже IE8 знает что такое `inline-block;` а так-же `:after, :before`. С `IE8+` верстать можно уже вполне сносно. А в IE9 работают даже такие фичи как `transform`. Мой вывод: если что-то плывёт в IE9 -- вёрстка некорректна! (ах да `box-sizing: border-box;` он так-же знает!)

Comment: @Олег Б, что-то простенькое и незатейливое - возможно, что-то посложнее и тут же приходится хаки использовать, остаётся надеяться что мелкомягкие, которые как минимум этим браузером заработали себе чан в Аду с мееедленным огнём, свою новую поделку так не испоганят.

Comment: @Олег Б, очень возможно, тогда значит сказался отсутствующий изначально Doctype и переход браузера в режим совместимости из-за этого.

Comment: по этой же странице, сейчас она так выглядит
http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=6717d8c4f59db27cd0548564cdbe661c 
а нужно чтоб, блок .inner вот так позиционировался
http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=5a8e1d2a6b34bd365fde75e1caa87993  
но почему то, он не хочет, хотя наружный .block имеет text-align:center, а .inner - left.
Как сделать это правильно и почему так не работает?

Comment: есть такое решение без inner: 
    htmlCalibrate: function(){
        var blockW = $('.block').width(), 
            item = $('.item'),
            itemW = item.width()+(parseInt(item.css('padding-left'))*2)+(parseInt(item.css("border-left-width"))*2);
        $('.block').css('padding-left',(blockW%itemW)/2);
    } 
но мне это не нравится, хочется без js